# Xml parsing Null value Handling

Tags: android, xml-parsing

Hi I am working with the android application which will parse the values and display with list view. I am using XML parsing method to parse the data and successfully displaying in listview. Now the problem is when I try to parse xml tag which does not having the value(NULL), It makes error and force close the app. I try to if the node having some value then only allow to parse still it is showing some problem and only the first tag is display in the first list item. And other list items are shows nothing.

```
Below is the xml tags to parse.

<UserScore>
<GameId>daily_1349375400</GameId>
<Location></Location>
<GameName>Football - 5th October 2013</GameName>
<Date>Oct 5, 2013</Date>
</UserScore>
−
<UserScore>
<GameId>136</GameId>
<GameName>Company Cricket</GameName>
<Location>France </Location>
<Date>Jan 6, 2012</Date>
</UserScore>

For the first time the location tag having "france" as its value, but when again played the second location tag contains nothing.
Here is my coding please tell me the solution.

public class AsynTaskScoreboard extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getParent(), "Retrieving data ", " Loading. Please wait ... ", true);

        // can use UI thread here
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
            this.dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                URL xpto = new URL(my url here);


                HttpURLConnection conn;

                conn = (HttpURLConnection) xpto.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true);

                conn.connect();
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

                try {

                    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                    Document doc = db.parse(is);
                    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                    NodeList nodeList;
                    nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("TotalPoints");
                    Log.d("Background", "TotalPoints " + nodeList);

                    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                        Node name = nodeList.item(i);
                        NodeList nodeEle = name.getChildNodes();
                        strTotalPoints = ((Node) nodeEle.item(0)).getNodeValue();
                        Log.d("Background", "TotalPoints " + nodeList);

                    }

                    nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("ChallengesPlayed");

                    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                        Node name = nodeList.item(i);
                        NodeList nodeEle = name.getChildNodes();
                        strChallengesPoint = ((Node) nodeEle.item(0)).getNodeValue();

                                            }

                    android.os.Message msg = Message.obtain();
                    msg.what = 11;
                    handler.sendMessage(msg);

                    /**
                     * Check whether it is my points or high score
                     */
                    switch (flagMypointsOrHighScore) {
                    case 0:
                        nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("UserScore");

                        // Define Array based on nodelist

                        arrLength = nodeList.getLength();
                        strGameid = new String[arrLength];
                        strGameNameArr = new String[arrLength];
                        strGameLocationArr = new String[arrLength];
                        strGameDate = new String[arrLength];



                        String[] strXMLTag = { "GameId", "GameName", "Location", "Date" };
                        for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {

                            Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                            Log.d("scoreList", "node " + node);
                            Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
                            Log.d("scoreList", "fstElmnt " + fstElmnt);
                            for (int j = 0; j < strXMLTag.length; j++) {
                                NodeList scoreList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName(strXMLTag[j]);
                                                                Element scoreElement = (Element) scoreList.item(0);
                                                                scoreList = scoreElement.getChildNodes();
                                                                switch (j) {
                                case 0:
                                    strGameid[i] = ((Node) scoreList.item(0)).getNodeValue();
                                                                        break;

                                case 1:
                                    strGameNameArr[i] = ((Node) scoreList.item(0)).getNodeValue();
                                                                        break;
                                case 2:


    strGameLocationArr[i]=((Node) scoreList.item(0)).getNodeValue();


                                    break;

                                case 3:
                                    strGameDate[i] = ((Node) scoreList.item(0)).getNodeValue();
                                                                        break;
                                }

                            }

                        }// End of for loop
                            // Your rank

                        break;

                    case 1:// Top rank 5

                        nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Top5Rank");

                        // Define Array based on nodelist

                        arrLength = nodeList.getLength();
                        strGameNameArr = new String[arrLength];
                        strGameLocationArr = new String[arrLength];
                        strGameDate = new String[arrLength];
                        for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {

                            Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                            Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;

                            NodeList rankList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("Person");
                            //
                            int rankListLength = rankList.getLength();

                            if (strPersonNameArr == null) {
                                strPersonNameArr = new String[rankListLength];
                                strPersonRankArr = new String[rankListLength];
                                strPersoonPointsArr = new String[rankListLength];
                            }
                            for (int j = 0; j < rankListLength; j++) {
                                rankList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("Person");
                                Element rankElement = (Element) rankList.item(j);
                                rankList = rankElement.getChildNodes();
                                strPersonNameArr[j] = rankElement.getAttribute("Name");

                                strPersonRankArr[j] = rankElement.getAttribute("Rank");

                                strPersoonPointsArr[j] = rankElement.getAttribute("Points");
                                                            }

                        }// End of for loop

                        break;

                    }// End of switch
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }// try below db 2try

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                if (e.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("java.net.SocketException: Network unreachable")) {
                    android.os.Message msg = android.os.Message.obtain();
                    msg.what = 0;
                    handler.sendMessage(msg);
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }// End of do in background method

        // do the stuff after the heavy task

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            android.os.Message msg = Message.obtain();
            switch (flagMypointsOrHighScore) {
            case 0:
                listViewMyPoints.setAdapter(new JR_LB_ListAdapter(ScoreboardActivity.this));
                break;
            case 1:
                listViewHighScores.setAdapter(new JR_LB_ListAdapter_HighScores(ScoreboardActivity.this));
                // Set textview value in the
                msg.what = 10;
                handler.sendMessage(msg);
                break;
            default:

            }

            if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
                this.dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }// End of on post execute method

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Totalpoint.setText(strTotalPoints);
            challengeplay.setText(strChallengesPoint);
            txtViewRank.setText(strRank);
            txtViewPoint.setText(strPoint);
            txtViewPersonName.setText(strPersonName);
            Log.d("ProgressUpdate", "strTotalPoints " + strTotalPoints);
            Log.d("ProgressUpdate", "strChallengesPoint " + strChallengesPoint);
            Log.d("ProgressUpdate", "strRank " + strRank);
            Log.d("ProgressUpdate", "strPoint " + strPoint);
        }

    }// End of Asynchronous task class
```

After the asynctask I passed the values via intent to next activity. at that the values also pass as null. Using that values I will proceed further activity. Please tell how to overcome this problem.

Comment: As I understand you you can detect if the required value is available or null. So how you handle the situation where your input data is incomplete is of course completely up to you app, how should anybody answer this?

Comment: I am checking with fstElement!=null. By this I can able to find i dont have any value in that object.

Comment: so what is the question then?

Comment: But still it shows the null pointer exception and the flow exits their itself, I just want If the location tag is null then continue with next tag and executes the loop as it works.

Comment: i would recommend you to single out the line where your app crashes in your question - i cant see any fstElement!=null in your code provided

Comment: Hi sorry I did after posting my question. So it is like this case2: if(fstElement1!=null) {  strGameLocationArr[i]=((Node) scoreList.item(0)).getNodeValue();
 } else if(fstElement==null) { strGameLocationArr[i]= "Nolocation";

Comment: better update your question it is really not very readable in this comment and also for other people who might want to help you